# Is it possible to switch browser tab?

Tags: javascript, browser, tabs, cross-browser

Here is my requirement,

I'm working on a enterprise application which is quite old, and it supports IE browser only. Now, there are chances that the user could open multiple tab/window from this application. I have written a custom timeout plugin for our purpose with [jQuery idleTimer Plugin](https://github.com/paulirish/jquery-idletimer/). When the countdown reaches 10 or less than 10, i need to switch to this tab/window to make the user aware that the page gets expired in less than 10 seconds.

So, is there a solution for this? I have tried `window.focus()` but does not work.

Comment: Maybe there's a better solution to detect which window is active and show the information there. Or in all open windows, it's the same application after all which should expire all tabs?

Comment: How about `alert('Your session is about to expire ...');`

Comment: [May be this can help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704206/how-to-change-browser-focus-from-one-tab-to-another)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a cross-browser way do switch a tab that's 100% reliable, especially in newer browsers. It's actively blocked in most newer browsers. As a user, I'm glad it's difficult in most cases, impossible in others to do this.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, setting a timeout for a Javascript alert in one page then move to another tab, the alert appearing after the timeout will trigger tab switch.

```
setTimeout(function(){ 
    alert("Switched tabs");
}, 
5000);
```

Comment: How can you implement the "Move" part?

Comment: The browser will do that automatically for you once the timeout period has expired

Comment: @AjayAradhya What I mean by "move" is even if you navigate to another page, the alert will always take you back to the tab which it is showing from

Comment: Wow. Soopar cool. I didn't know that. That should work fine here. Thanks :)