# How to set focus to child and opener windows when tabbed

Tags: javascript, browser

How do I set focus back to the parent window when in another browser tab? I've tried:

```
window.opener.focus();
```

to no avail.  It only seems to work when the windows are not docked.

I need this to work in Chrome, IE9/10, Firefox, and Safari.

Internet Explorer also seems to have issues setting focus to a child window. E.g. when using:

```
var windowRef = window.open(url);
```

then later from the same tab:

```
windowRef.focus(); // ok in Chrome, doesn't seem to work in IE...
```

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you want to achieve? To set the focus **inside** the other window to the first link / button / form field / whatever? Or to make the other window (browser tab) the active browser tab?

Anyways - maybe the `opener.focus()` call doesn't work because both windows are not served from the same origin. Try setting up a communication channel via [postMessage](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/web-messaging.html#crossDocumentMessages) to resolve this. So in the `opener` document, listen for an event like this:

```
window.addEventListener('message', function (event) {
    window.focus();
}, false);
```

And in the opened window, send the message like this:

```
opener.postMessage('foo', '*');
```

Sadly, I can't test if this is working right now. (I guess it should, though...)

A few things to add, though:

1. Some legacy crap browsers don't support postMessage (see [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#search=postMessage)). There are workarounds, though. :)
2. I used the W3 standard notation for attaching the event listener. IE8 and below use their proprietary `attachEvent` equivalent.
3. You should replace the `'*'` origin wildcard with the actual origin of the opener window.
4. In the message event listener function, you should inspect event.origin and only run your actual payload if the origin is correct.

Comment: Thanks defaude, I'll give this a go and let you know

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't work either :( - Yes, my intention is to make the other browser tab the active tab.

Comment: Hmm, too bad. If I can find the time, I will look into testing this and probably find a solution for you :)

Comment: Really sorry, but I guess this won't be possible :(