# Is it possible to focus a webpage programatically using javascript?

Tags: javascript, focus

I have a javascript extension on top of Gmail.

Say a user navigates to some other website xyz.com.

And If there is a very important update from my extension 
**I want to automatically navigate the user back to the Gmail form my javascript code.**

Is this possible? I have tried `window.focus()` but it does not seem to work.

Any other suggestions please. Thanks.

Comment: It is not possible for security reasons.
It seems a duplicate of [How to change browser focus from one tab to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704206/how-to-change-browser-focus-from-one-tab-to-another).

Comment: Above mentioned question was asked "7 years, 1 month ago", I thought there could be some latest developments. @kairos