# Select browser tab that was opened by current tab

Tags: javascript, focus

I have a web page with a link that opens another page in a new tab. In the newly opened page, I have a link that, when clicked, should bring focus to the original tab.

The new tab is opened via the `target` attribute:

```
<a href="/new-page/" target="_BLANK">new tab</a>
```

I thought this should work:

```
<a href="#" class="back-link">switch tabs</a>

$('.back-link').click(function() { 
    if(window.opener) {
      console.log('switching tabs');
      window.opener.focus();
    }
 });
```

The `console.log` fires, but focus stays on the current tab. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Could post the and js where the tab is opened as well?

Comment: @jasper - it did it with the `target` of the `<a>` tag - see updated OP

Answer (score 1):

Could you try adding the following event listener to your `new tab` button instead of `target="_blank"` :

```
$('.new-tab-button').click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
    window.open('/new-page/');
 });
```

This way you actually open a new window instead of new tab, according to the stackoverflow thread linked below, for security reasons, it seems to only be possible to focus to (and maybe from) windows/pop-ups. I'm not sure if what you're trying to do is possible but if so this could be it.

[How to change browser focus from one tab to another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704206/how-to-change-browser-focus-from-one-tab-to-another/35896395)