# How to recall browser tab with previous instance on same page

Tags: javascript, html, tampermonkey

I have a page with a few links.
Each link opens in a new tab.
The next time I click a given link, I want it to recall the same tab where it was previously opened.
Is it possible? How?
All pages come from the same domain.

I've seen this answer: 
[Check if my website is open in another tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23690666/check-if-my-website-is-open-in-another-tab#answer-43291970)
It seems possible to store the URIs in localStorage, for repetitions detection.
I think this technique will allow me to detect repetitions, but I can't figure out how to aim at the specific tab (activate it, bring it to the front).
I don't control the server, need to implement it in the client (via Tampermonkey).

For the curious, I work a lot with BitBucket issues.
The page with the links is the issues listing, the other pages are the individual issues.
I want to be protected from opening the same issue twice, update both versions, and have a data loss.
Additionally, each page can have two different URIs, one for viewing and the other for editing. But I think I can solve it with JS.

Answer (score 2):

### Recalling a Browser Tab by Name

You can first specify a name for each tab you create, by using `window.open()`:

```js
let newWindow = window.open(newUrl, newWindowName);
```

or by using `target` attribute in an anchor tag:

```
<a href="http://my-new-url" href="myNewWindowName">Make New Window</a>
```

If you then call `window.open` with the name of an existing tab, that will use the existing tab. If the window by that name doesn't exist, `window.open` will create a new window (or tab).

MDN web docs page for [Window.open](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)

---

#### Bringing Window to the Front

Using `window.open()` alone may not be enough to bring the window to the front. That may be possible with a different function, [window.focus()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/focus), which issues a request to bring the window to the front. Combining the two:

```
window.open(myUrl, myWindowName).focus();
```

**Caution**: A browser's user preference setting may still prevent focus() from bringing the window to the front, so this is not guaranteed to work. From MDN web docs:

> It may fail due to user settings and the window isn't guaranteed to be frontmost before this method returns.

Comment: Nice! It seems feasible. I would have to take control of the links of the index page and replace them with `window.open` commands.

Comment: @JuanLanus I *think* you could just put the name in the links `target=` attribute. It's usually used for `target="_blank"`, but I think it does accept any name.

Comment: @TomášZato-ReinstateMonica: will give it a try, sounds useful to simplify the needed code.  
Yes, it accepts anything, so I could use a repeatable slug to addres each issue page, something like "issue1234" (no "#" pls).

Answer (score 0):

You can get the previous page's URL with the following:

```
let prevURL = document.referrer;
```

You can get the URLs from all open tabs with the `windows.getAll()` [function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/windows/getAll).

From this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2704206/how-to-change-browser-focus-from-one-tab-to-another) - You cannot programmatically focus the browser to a specific tab due to security concerns. Consider updating the title to notify the user with `document.title = {{new title}}`

Comment: yes, I can not, but...  
If instead of a Tampermonkey script I write an extension, and enable the "tabs" permission, then I'll be able to use the windows object that you brought up at will. This is good!